# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 89

Tags: c#, asp.net

kindly assist.
am getting the following error in my code ;

```
 constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\DAKTARI\\Desktop\\smarttable.xls;Extended Properties=''Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;''", FilePath);
```

Line 26:         Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);

kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

You used [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx), but never used the `FilePath` variable anywhere in that string. You need to set it instead of your path using a `{0}` - since it's a parameter in position 0 (it's the first and only parameter in you case`).

The error, however, is caused by you using double `''` in your `Extended Properties` section, you only need one `'`.

Please try the following:

```
 constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'", FilePath);
```

---

**Some more explenations about [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

When you use `string.Format`, you pass it string parameters to be replaced with `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}` etc.

So, for example,

```
string.Format("Hello {0}, how are you {1}?", "John", "today");
```

Will result in a string:

```
"Hello John, how are you today?"
```

Comment: Thanks @Koby..i have removed the double quotes and changed the connection string to constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'", FilePath); but am now getting this error;  Could not find installable ISAM

Comment: @johnkc That's a whole other issue and should be posted as a new question. Kindly accept my answer as correct and refer to this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/209805/you-receive-a-could-not-find-installable-isam-error-message-or-some-fi. If you still have issues, please post a new question and ping me with the link to that question here.

Comment: Thanks @Koby..would you kindly send me a code that simply imports data from excel to database table using asp.net and c#..this one is giving me headaches..and include for me the web.config code also...